# Tasker parse json

Tags: javascript, android, json, tasker

I'm creating a task where the weather is pulled by an http request this is what I've got so far:

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="5.10.1">
    <Task sr="task79">
        <cdate>1494395940378</cdate>
        <edate>1604394719692</edate>
        <id>79</id>
        <nme>Create Weather Alert</nme>
        <pri>100</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%json</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3"> </Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>339</code>
            <Bundle sr="arg0">
                <Vals sr="val">
                    <net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES>&lt;StringArray sr=""&gt;&lt;_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES0&gt;%http_file_output
File Output
Will always contain the file's full path even if you specified a directory as the File to save.&lt;/_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES0&gt;&lt;_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES1&gt;%http_response_code
Response Code
The HTTP Code the server responded&lt;/_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES1&gt;&lt;_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES2&gt;%http_cookies
Cookies
The cookies the server sent in the response in the Cookie:COOKIE_VALUE format. You can use this directly in the 'Headers' field of the HTTP Request action&lt;/_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES2&gt;&lt;_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES3&gt;%http_headers()
Response Headers
The HTTP Headers the server sent in the response. Each header is in the 'key:value' format&lt;/_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES3&gt;&lt;_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES4&gt;%http_response_length
Response Length
The size of the response in bytes&lt;/_array_net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES4&gt;&lt;/StringArray&gt;</net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES>
                    <net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES-type>[Ljava.lang.String;</net.dinglisch.android.tasker.RELEVANT_VARIABLES-type>
                </Vals>
            </Bundle>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg10" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg2" ve="3">http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=54.5234936&amp;lon=-1.3049079&amp;appid=<----APIKEY---->&amp;units=metric&amp;cnt=5</Str>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3">Download/weather.json</Str>
            <Int sr="arg8" val="30"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="0"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>417</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Download/weather.json</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%json</Str>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%json</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act4" ve="7">
            <code>129</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">var parsedjson=JSON.parse(global('json'));
setLocal('test',parsedjson.cod);
flashLong(local('test'));</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="45"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act5" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%parsedjson</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act6" ve="7">
            <code>129</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">var test="test";</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="45"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act7" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%test</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Img sr="icn" ve="2">
            <nme>hl_aaa_ext_sun</nme>
        </Img>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

The %json variable get filled with this:

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1604394000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 5.69,
        "feels_like": 1.68,
        "temp_min": 5.69,
        "temp_max": 5.99,
        "pressure": 1011,
        "sea_level": 1011,
        "grnd_level": 1008,
        "humidity": 81,
        "temp_kf": -0.3
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 49
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 3.5,
        "deg": 196
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2020-11-03 09:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2636005,
    "name": "Thornaby",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 54.52,
      "lon": -1.3
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 22356,
    "timezone": 0,
    "sunrise": 1604387520,
    "sunset": 1604420727
  }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is getting simple values from the json.
I tried doing that here

```
var parsedjson=JSON.parse(global('json'));
setLocal('test',parsedjson.cod);
flashLong(local('test'));
```

Not only isn't flashLong doing anything, when the last step of the task (flash) runs I only see "%test".

Also, to make sure, let's say I want to get "temp" from the json the regular syntax applies right?

```
parsedjson.list[0].main.temp
```

Can anyone help me understand why %test isn't being filled like I want it?

DISCLAIMER: I know about autotools. But I'd prefer to do it this way as I don't use autotools for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Taskers' globals starts with first capital letter. Should be:
`var parsedjson=JSON.parse(global('json'));`

Answer (score 0):

I know its been awhile, but for whoever might come across this -
Starting from version 5.12, tasker supports parsing JSON without the need of additional packages.

So, to get `cod`'s value, you can just simply:

```
SetVariable:
    Name: %test_var
    To: %json.cod
    Structured Output: Checked
```

To get the temperature - set the variable to `%json.list[0].main.temp`